# Can I use the same model with different input tensors? Should I avoid running session.run() multiple times?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, iterator, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to build a graph with trainining and validation of the same model (fully-connected MLP) without re-running the session, without using feed_dict and using tf.data. Generally, using feed_dict I would define the model with input tensor X and I would evaluate the tensors loss or accuracy. Then, during the graph execution I would code something like

```
...
#Training
session.run([train_op], feed_dict={X: XTrainingData, Y: YTrainingData})
#Validation
session.run([accuracy_validation], feed_dict={X: XValidationData, Y: YValidationData})
```

I know how to use dataset for training and avoid feed_dict. My question is: how can I avoid feed_dict for training AND validation? If X comes from an iterator I will call .get_next() twice (one for training X1, one for validation X2), How can I build the graph to use X1 and X2?

More generally, should I avoid to call session.run() multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

The session.run() call for validation will be simply feedforward network which will take very less time and also memory. So it should not a big deal if you are using it multiple times. You can try having another validation op with different input placeholders for X1 and Y1 and pass these tensors to your model and validate.

```
x1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,256,256,1],dtype='float32',name='input_img')
y1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,256,256,1],dtype='float32',name='output_img')
x2 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,256,256,1],dtype='float32',name='val_input_img')
y2 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,256,256,1],dtype='float32',name='val_output_img')

pred = mod(x1) #mod is the network
val = mod(x2)  #prediction for validation
los = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-y1))
val_los = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(val-y2)) # validation loss
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
train = opt.minimize(los)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

And then do something like this

```
_,val_lo = session.run([train,val_los],feed_dict={x1:xtr,y1:ytr,x2:xval,ytr:yval})
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me some details on how you define mod? the val prediction will have the same weights of pred?

Comment: It should use the same weights. If you are using tensorflow's high level api such as keras then that is taken care of I guess. Even with low level api if you put reuse= True within the tf.variable_scope it should work fine I feel. I have never come across any such case where old weights are used instead of the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem to feeding the validation set into the data pipeline in the same way ?